# Погасает/чернеет экран в ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

С самой установки Ubuntu возникла проблема: просто погасает экран, начинает мигать разными оттенками черного в некоторых окнах, сайтах.
Например: открываю сайт ВК, всё работает, но стоит мне открыть страницу чью-то или свою, как сразу чернеет экран, до того пока я не перейду на другую ссылку.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Используемое железо и список драйверов дайте пожалуйста?

Comment: обновть биос, поставить фирмварь свежий, использовать свежее ядро.
напишите чо за проц, видео и материнская плата

Comment: Не могу понять, как связана "проблема с установкой Ubuntu" с чёрным экраном при попытке входа на ВК ?!!!!

Comment: @Sergey с момента установки - тоесть сразу.

Comment: @eri *с момента установки* - т.е. раньше у Вас убунта НЕ стояла? А как Вы запускали браузер, что бы зайти на ВК? Под виндой?  Или же речь идёт не об установке, а про **обновление** ? По любому : надо сначала выяснить - это проблема браузера, или проблема дисплейного менеджера? Установите ещё какой-нибудь браузер и посмотрите как в нём отображается ВК.  Если нормально - значит проблема в браузере.

Comment: @Sergey а помоему человек почти ясно всё расписал) только б инфу о железе добавил

Answer (score 0):

## AMD/RADEON

Для корректной работы драйвера видео AMD требуется firmware. Свежее [брал тут](https://github.com/q3aql/amdgpu-firmware-update).
Без него Rysen или A6 работают в через фреймбуфер с эмуляцией 3Д ускорения - не очень совместимый механизм (llvmpipe).

Также установите пакеты amd64-microcode и firmware-* для другого оборудования.

Сам драйвер AMD для современных видюх поставляется с ядром Linux. Поставьте свежую версию Убунту (18.04+) или обновитесь [через бакпорты](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports)

Обновление BIOS на материнских платах с AM4 можно сказать обязательно для стабильной работы Linux. Пропадают некоторые артефакты.

[Старые карточки требуют драйвера fglrx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)

## INTEL

Если у вас Атом N450 или подобный EEPC нетбук - нормально работает только Убунту 12.04.
Современные видеокарты работают без проблем.

## NVIDIA

Если сразу хорошо не заработало, то нужно ставить родной драйвер
[https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/драйвер_видеокарт_nvidia](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82_nvidia)